# Understanding low probabilities as result of the Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, bayesian

I'm having trouble understanding why the results of some of my computations are so low considering the data I have.

An easy example:
Lets assume we have a dataset of 1000 people. 600 of them have eaten something today, 400 have not. Of those 600 who have eaten today, 50 are dehydrated and 20 are malnourished.
Of the 400 people that did not eat today, 350 are dehydrated and 250 are malnourished.

Now I want to calculate the probability of a person having eaten today, given the person is both dehydrated and malnourished.

P(has eaten|dehydrated, malnourished) = 6/10 * 5/12 * 1/30 = 0.008 which seems plausibly low, however
P(has not eaten|dehydrated, malnouished) = 4/10 * 7/8 * 5/8 = 0.36 which is the result I'm having trouble with.

Yes, it is the most likely outcome, but the probability seems wayyyy too low considering almost every person in the dataset that is both dehydrated and malnourished has not eaten today.

I guess there is some stupid mistake or perhaps I haven't fully understood the Bayes Theorem, can somebody give me a hand?

Comment: Note that what you are calculating is not a conditional probability by rather the joint probability. Consider normalizing accordingly in order for it to be the conditional probability